# ESTA payment not processed

Tags: esta, payment

I filled all my credit card info to pay for the ESTA, it says processing and then goes back to the page where it says it is unpaid. No error message appears. Did it with another credit card and it did the same thing.

Comment: What does your bank statements say? Did you pay? Have you contacted your bank?